# When I Filter my listview and click the item i get a wrong data

Tags: android

When I Filter my listview and click the item i get a wrong data .. it always get the first data on the list.

```
public class DisplayActivity extends Activity {

private DbHelper mHelper;
private ArrayList<String> listall;
private ArrayAdapter<String> userAdapter;
private ListView obj;
private EditText edt;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_activity);
    mHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    final ArrayList<String> array_list = mHelper.getAllFriends();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

    edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    obj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);
    obj.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         int id_To_Search = position + 1;
            String id = String.valueOf(id_To_Search);
            Intent i = new Intent(DisplayActivity.this, EditFriends.class);
            i.putExtra("id", id);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    if (arrayAdapter != null) {
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
}
```

Comment: why in onResume() notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: i have no problem with that i just refresh my arrayAddapter..

Answer (score 0):

What you doing here is to get the position from the current list. When you apply the filter your list get shorten and data changes their positon accordingly. If you expecting the position same as id as in your original list you won't get that.

1.You need to use custom Array adapter with an interface.

2.Implement that interface in the Activity.

3.Pass activity object to adapter.

4.Implement onclick inside the adapter and pass the call the interface method with activity object. Also pass your ID in that. then you can collect the id in the activity now.

You can take the example from here [Creating custom adapter with listener](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/9e8439/create-custom-listener-on-button-in-listitem-listview-in-a/)

Feel free to comment. Thanks